# what is the issue with my training & test sets?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, training-data

I'm creating a recommender system using collabrative filtering, im using the grouplens ml-100k as the dataset and using the Surprise import and numpy to handle it. However i noticed an issue when running an RMSE test on the testset when i tried to split the testset from the training set. Saying the predictions was empty.

I tried to just skip past it and comment it off, but now the issue may have remained with the a Value error to do with an Item 0.

```
# import necessary libraries
import numpy as np
from surprise import SVD
from surprise import Dataset
from surprise import accuracy
from surprise import Reader
from surprise.model_selection import train_test_split

# load the dataset
data = Dataset.load_builtin('ml-100k')

# define the algorithm
algo = SVD()

# split the data into training and testing sets
trainset, testset = train_test_split(data, test_size=.25)
"""
# filter out items not in trainset
testset = [x for x in testset if x[1] in trainset.all_items()]
"""
# train the algorithm on the training set
algo.fit(trainset)
"""
# make predictions on the testing set
predictions = algo.test(testset)

# calculate RMSE (Root Mean Squared Error)
accuracy.rmse(predictions)
"""
# recommend items to a specific user
user_id = '196'
items_to_recommend = []

# get all the items that the user hasn't rated
if user_id in trainset._raw2inner_id_users:  # check if user id is present in the trainset
    user_inner_id = trainset.to_inner_uid(user_id)
    user_ratings = trainset.ur[user_inner_id]
    for item_id in trainset.all_items():
        inner_item_id = trainset.to_inner_iid(item_id)
        if not np.in1d(inner_item_id, user_ratings[:,0]): # check if item id is not in user ratings
            items_to_recommend.append(item_id)

# predict ratings for all items that the user hasn't rated
user_items = [(user_id, item_id, 4.0) for item_id in items_to_recommend] # 4.0 is a placeholder rating
item_ratings = algo.test(user_items)

# if item_ratings is empty, recommend the most popular items
if len(item_ratings) == 0:
    item_popularity = defaultdict(int)
    for (u, i, r) in trainset.all_ratings():
        item_popularity[i] += 1
    sorted_items = sorted(item_popularity.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    items_to_recommend = [iid for (iid, _) in sorted_items][:10]
    print(f"No recommendations found for user {user_id}. Recommending the most popular items.")
else:
    # sort the predicted ratings in descending order
    item_ratings.sort(key=lambda x: x.est, reverse=True)
    # print the top 10 recommended items for the user
    print(f"Top 10 items recommended for user {user_id}:")
    for item in item_ratings[:10]:
        print(f"Item ID: {item.iid}, Estimated Rating: {item.est}")
```

I'm new to using surprise and numpy, so any guidance would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] Saying the predictions was empty.

The issue comes from the test set filtering step :

```py
# filter out items not in trainset
testset = [x for x in testset if x[1] in trainset.all_items()]
```

`x[1]` is actually a string (like `'123'`) and `trainset.all_items()` a range. Thus the condition `x[1] in trainset.all_items()` will always be False.

Simply cast `x[1]` into an int and it should work fine

```py
testset = [x for x in testset if int(x[1]) in trainset.all_items()]
```

Comment: thank you so much bro. however, i got another snag on line 39, with the error 'ValueError: Item 0 is not part of the trainset.' any further help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Same issue ;) line 39 you're testing if `user_id` is in `trainset.all_items()` (range). But you previously declare `user_id = '196'` (string). Make sure the ids are integer before checking if it's in  `trainset.all_items()`